# push 1 element from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

i know this is possible but not sure about my situation. so currently i have 2 arrays. one is for adverts, the other is for events. Id like to add one advert for every 3 Events. Simple explanation of how they currently are.

Events Array:

```
$Events =Array('Event 1','Event 2','Event 3','Event 4','Event 5','Event 6','Event 7') ;
```

Adverts Array:

```
$Adverts =Array('Advert 1','Advert 2');
```

Target Array:

```
$Target = Array('Event 1','Event 2','Event 3','Advert 1','Event 4','Event 5','Event 6','Advert 2');
```

ive currently chunked the events array so that they are in groups of 3.

Comment: Alright, we understood the problem. Now show us, what have you tried? Like, looping or any array functions???

Comment: There are zillions of ways to achieve this simple goal. What have you tried?

Comment: simple maps, and foreach loops lol im not experienced with php so i may not have used both of these methods to their full potential

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `array_splice` .

This should work.

```
 $event_array = ['Event 1','Event 2','Event 3','Event 4','Event 5','Event 6','Event 7'];
$advert_array = ['Advert 1','Advert 2'];
//Push array value;
array_splice($event_array, 3, 0,array($advert_array[0]));
//Add to index 3
array_splice($event_array, 3, 0,$advert_array[0]);
print_r($event_array);
```

**Result**

```
Array ( [0] => Event 1 [1] => Event 2 [2] => Event 3 [3] => Advert 1 [4] => Event 4 [5] => Event 5 [6] => Event 6 [7] => Advert 2 )
```

Comment: Wrong output in field 5

Comment: Done Thank you :)

Comment: this spits out.. E,E,E,A,A,E,E,E instead of E,E,E,A,E,E,E,A. very close i might play around with it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$Events =array('Event 1','Event 2','Event 3','Event 4','Event 5','Event 6','Event 7') ;
$Adverts =array('Advert 1','Advert 2');
$Target =array();

$AdvertCount = 0;
foreach ($Events as $key => $Event) {
    array_push($Target,$Event);
    if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        array_push($Target,$Adverts[$AdvertCount]);
        $AdvertCount++;
    }
}

print_r($Target);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to do it is to iterate over `$Adverts` and for each item of `$Adverts` extract three items from `$Events`:

```
$Events = array('Event 1','Event 2','Event 3','Event 4','Event 5','Event 6','Event 7');
$Adverts = array('Advert 1','Advert 2');

$Target = array();
// The current position in $Events
$i = 0;
foreach ($Adverts as $advert) {
    // Append 3 events and the current advert
    $Target = array_merge($Target, array_slice($Events, $i, 3), array($advert));
    // Skip over the 3 events just processed
    $i += 3;
}
```

To make sure you don't run out of events you should compute the number of iterations first. The code below puts in `$Target` only complete groups of 3 events + 1 advert.

```
// The number of events in each group
$nbEvents = 3;
// The number of groups; each group contains $nbEvents events + 1 advert
$nbGroups = min((int)(count($Events)/$nbEvents), count($Adverts));

$Target = array();
// Iterate over $Adverts but process only $nbGroups items
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbGroups; $i ++) {
    // Append $nbEvents events and the current advert
    $Target = array_merge(
        $Target,
        array_slice($Events, $nbEvents * $i, $nbEvents),
        array($Adverts[$i])
    );
}
```